# Windows Phone 8 development on Windows 7 - is it or will be possible?

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-phone-8

I was trying to install Windows Phone 8 SDK on my Windows 7 machine and it hit me with the 'supported only on Windows 8' message. I actually wanted to develop Phone 7.5 apps on Visual Studio 2012, impossible thing with the 7.1 SDK, so I thought 8 SDK will do the job.

As if it was not enough that the 8 SDK was controversial upon release, now that it's generally available, to me it seems like a horrible decision to make it available only for Windows 8, because in my humble opinion, no serious and sane developer will install Windows 8 ever, or at least in the near future, just because of the Metro UI.

So, anyone knows any workarounds for developing Windows Phone 8 on Windows 7, or at least develop for 7.5 but using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: It annoyed me at first too, I have one machine which I won't upgrade to Win8 because I'm not sure how my Steam collection will cope. But otherwise I've been pleased with the experience of Windows 8.

Comment: It has to be possible to develop Windows Phone 7.5 with the 7.1 SDK since the Windows Phone 7.8 update to the Windows Phone 7 SDK has not been released ( nor any information with regards to the next Windows Phone 7 update 0).  **The solution of course is to use VS2010 for your Windows Phone 7 needs.**

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Visual Studio 2010 was great, but Visual Studio 2012 is even better, and I've been using it since the CTP came out about a year ago, so it's going to be awkward to get back to 2010.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the particulars of 3rd party toolset configurations, namely visual studio, windows phone devleopment, and windows operating systems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope, it's all Windows 8 unfortunately. A reason is the hypervisor in Windows 8 is used to emulate or virtualise Windows phone 8 machines. That and marketing of course.

Edit:

AS for developers using Windows 8, I use it on all my laptops now and like it. I run Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 under it with no issues.

Comment: Thing is, I also like Windows 8 when it comes to speed and fluency. But the thing that annoys me the most is the removal of the start button (at least an option to enable it) and the poor apps that were made just to be there, and not to provide any sort of functionality. In a word, I hate that the Metro UI (which is not bad by itself, but is bad for non-touch devices) is forcibly imposed to me as an user.

Comment: Yeah, I like the new start menu actually because I used to pin all the apps I used to the front of the old start menu anyway, so it's just a bigger more colourful version for me. I don't use ANY "metro/ModernUI" apps though.

Comment: And make sure to install win8 64 bits if you want to play with wpsdk

Comment: @Tiby One of my team member uses stardock to get the start menu on windows http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/ and quite happy with it. Their other product looks interesting as well http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/features.asp

Answer (score 2):

(Your have probably already found a solution for your problem, but i think this might be useful to other that, as me, are setting their environment for the first time.)

[Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) includes Visual Studio 2012 Express.

If you install it on a virtual machine, like explained in this Nokia Developer Wiki [article](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator), you should be able to continue using your Windows 7 machine and avoid moving to Windows 8, while having a working WP8 Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason being that windows 8 apps and WP8 apps use the new WinRT runtime don't support .NET, you can't run winRT on Windows 7 so your apps won't compile. You could create metro style apps with WPF, but they won't run on Windows 8 (at least not in metro/modern mode).

Comment: He's trying to develop Windows _Phone_ 8 apps, not Windows 8 apps. Confusing naming scheme, I know.

Comment: Windows Phone 8 apps must also be developed using windows 8, as Ian pointed out the Windows 8 Phone SDK requires Hyper-V virtualization in order to emulate the phone.